# How to operate git rebase editor?

Tags: git

macOS

I want to delete a merge commit

```
9d84a45 (HEAD -> staging) Merge branch 'development' into staging
```

I try to use git command

```
git rebase -i 9d84a45
```

Terminal shows the result and then I want to type `drop 9d84a45`
but I don't know how to use the editor

[image]

Comment: Git will use whatever editor you configure in the `core.editor` configuration setting. If you're not familiar with whichever editor it's using by default, then configure it to use one that you prefer.

Comment: This editor is called vi or vim. Look for tutorials. The escape hatch here is to type `dG` to delete all text from the current line to the end, then `:wq<ENTER>` to write the empty file and exit. Then configure [`core.editor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreeditor) or [`sequence.editor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-sequenceeditor). The reason to make the file empty is that Git takes it as a signal to abort the operation. Just quitting out without making changes does *not* abort the operation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596835/7976758

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git interactive rebase no commits to pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485508/git-interactive-rebase-no-commits-to-pick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that merge commit is the most recent commit on the staging branch (which the decoration '`HEAD -> staging`' seems to indicate), then you do not need an interactive rebase (and its associated editor):

```
git switch staging
git reset --hard @~1
# done
```